# Failed to negotiate HTTPS connection with server using HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, ssl, httpclient, httpwebrequest, tls1.2

I need to implement a payment API on my project (based on .Net 4.0).
The URL is alike https://xx.xx.xxx.xx/crm, when I browse it on any browser it's accessible but it's insecure, No SSL certification/authentication.

From the provide API, I get data on POSTMAN when I uncheck "Enable SSL Certificate Validation". I use Fiddler Composer for testing (disabling SSL check) too. But, it can't acquire data and shows me this message:

```
[Fiddler] The connection to '10.16.105.30' failed. <br />System.Security.SecurityException Failed to negotiate HTTPS connection with server.fiddler.network.https&gt; HTTPS handshake to 10.16.105.30 (for #977) failed. System.IO.IOException Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
```

Fiddler Network analysis for POSTMAN request:

```
A SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted the parameters below.
Version: 3.3 (TLS/1.2)
Random: 50 8D F5 D7 41 D7 3A EE 92 E0 FB 76 30 24 07 4A 1D 73 01 89 E7 98 79 04 45 F9 98 EC C5 84 B5 02
"Time": 10/24/2084 8:45:36 AM
SessionID: 1C D9 68 FD CE 74 3C 6C 1C C4 B1 DE EA E3 87 9A 80 0C A5 BD FD 51 BA 50 3B 22 0A 96 92 13 90 1C
Extensions:
server_name 10.16.105.30
extended_master_secret empty
renegotiation_info 00
supported_groups x25519 [0x1d], secp256r1 [0x17], secp384r1 [0x18]
ec_point_formats uncompressed [0x0]
SessionTicket empty
signature_algs ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha1
key_share 00 24 00 1D 00 20 46 BB 2D EC 3C 4D 5E F2 AE 00 74 C8 BB 0C 8C 4E 84 1E AC A0 06 B0 A0 0B 4B E3 DE E6 14 4F F3 75
psk_key_exchange_modes 01 01
supported_versions Tls1.3, Tls1.2, Tls1.1
Ciphers:
[1301] TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
[1302] TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
[1303] TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
[C02F] TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
[C02B] TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
[C030] TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
[C02C] TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
[CCA9] TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
[CCA8] TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
[C009] TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
[C013] TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
[C00A] TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
[C014] TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
[009C] TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
[009D] TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
[002F] TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
[0035] TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
[000A] SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA
Compression:
[00] NO_COMPRESSION
```

I implement that API on my project using HttpWebRequest (POST) and get exceptions.

```
Message : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
Data : {}
InnerException : System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest
asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest
asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback,
Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object
state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object
state)
at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
TargetSite : System.Net.WebResponse GetResponse(System.Net.WebRequest)
HResult : -2146233079
```

I search for this exception and get these solutions everywhere.

To set Security protocol

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

And to disable SSL verification:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslpolicy) => true;
```

Code:

```
public string PostRequest(string url, string accessToken, string requestData)
{
try
{
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
//ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)48 | (SecurityProtocolType)192 |
// (SecurityProtocolType)768 | (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslpolicy) => true;
ServicePointManager.CheckCertificateRevocationList = false;
var byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestData);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", accessToken);
using (var dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Flush();
dataStream.Close();
}
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
var responseFromServer = "";
using (var dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
if (dataStream != null)
{
var reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
dataStream.Flush();
dataStream.Close();
}
response.Close();
return responseFromServer;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
return e.Message.ToString();
}
}
```

Fiddler Network analysis for HTTPWEBREQUEST request:

```
A SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted the parameters below.
Version: 3.3 (TLS/1.2)
Random: 60 04 29 99 4D AF EC CB D2 76 AC 8B D1 B1 F4 5D A1 64 F5 3C 05 73 13 F8 9F 22 C9 04 68 14 B2 05
"Time": 6/6/2051 12:22:24 AM
SessionID: empty
Extensions:
supported_groups secp256r1 [0x17], secp384r1 [0x18]
ec_point_formats uncompressed [0x0]
signature_algs rsa_pkcs1_sha512, ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_sha1, dsa_sha1
SessionTicket empty
extended_master_secret empty
renegotiation_info 00
Ciphers:
[C028] TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
[009F] TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
[009E] TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
[009D] TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
[009C] TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
[C02B] TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
[C023] TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
[C027] TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
[C014] TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
[C013] TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
[003D] TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
[003C] TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
[0035] TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
[002F] TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
[C02C] TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
[C024] TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
[C00A] TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
[C009] TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
[006A] TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
[0040] TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
[0038] TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
[0032] TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
[000A] SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA
[0013] SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA
[0005] SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
[0004] SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
Compression:
[00] NO_COMPRESSION
```

I tried hard to solve this issue, but did not get any good result. Please, help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Add following to beginning of your code : ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Comment: @jdweng I tried the way you described, but, it's not working. I get exception: "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send."

Comment: Since the server closed the connection information would be needed on what the server actually supports. All you show is the ClientHello currently and from this on can only speculate why the server likes one ClientHello but not the other.  It might a problem with the ciphers, it might be a problem with the TLS version (Postman supports TLS 1.3, your client not) ... - impossible to be sure. If possible look at the server side for code, configuration, logs ...

Comment: Only TLS 1.2 and 1.3 are valid.  Other are obsolete and will cause failures (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.securityprotocoltype?view=net-5.0).  I would try HTTP (not HTTPS) since Postman is working without a valid certification check.  If server required a certificate that Postman would fail.